# CakePHP validation not working for contact form

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I am trying to do some very simple validation in my CakePHP contact form, but validation does not work eventhough I think I did everything necessary. Here's what I did:

1. I made a model like this:

   ```
   class Office extends AppModel
   {
     var $name = 'Office';
     var $useTable = false;
     public $validate = array('onderwerp' => 'notEmpty');
   }
   ```

   (I also tried many other values for `$validate` from the CakePHP online manual)
2. In Config/bootstrap.php I made this rule for not letting CakePHP expect plural "Offices":

   ```
   Inflector::rules('plural', array('rules' => array(), 
       'irregular' => array(), 
       'uninflected' => array('office')));
   ```
3. In OfficeController, I do this in my method `contact()`:

   ```
   $this->Office->set($this->request->data);
   if($this->Office->validates()){
     echo "code validates";
   } else {
     print_r($this->Office->validationErrors);
   }
   ```
4. And in my `Office/contact.ctp` view, I have (amongst other code like starting and ending the form) this code:

   `$this->Form->input('onderwerp', array('label'=>false, 'size' => 60));`

Now, even when I fill in the form, leaving empty the field 'onderwerp', it executes the code that should be executed when the code is executed.

When I `print_r($this->request->data)` or `print_r($this->Office)` I see that my `onderwerp` field is there and that it is empty (or filled when I do fill in something).

Now, when I add a `public function validates()` in my model and `echo` something there, it IS being displayed. So I'd say CakePHP knows where to find my model, and does execute my controller code. I also tried adding `return parent::validates();` in my `validates()` function, but this also yielded no validation error, or any other error for that matter. My debug level is set to `2`.

I guess I'm missing a needle in this haystack. Thanks for helping me finding it!

Comment: the inflector rule is unnecessary, so is $name. the key question: how does your Form->create() look like?

Comment: also try to use schema etc for better validation and form input handling: http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

Comment: Oh, gosh, that was the needle. Thanks a lot, mark! My Form->create looked like `$this->Form->create('Contact');`. But of course it must be `$this->Form->create('Office');`, named after my controller, not my action. In retrospect it always seems so obvious...

Comment: again, not quite ;) named after the model (which is the scope here).

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Thanks again. Will give you an upvote as soon as I have 15 reputation!

Comment: Finally, here's my upvote. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so drop all the inflector stuff.

and use the right model in your Form->create()

either

```
$this->Form->create(null)
```

or

```
$this->Form->create('Office');
```

and if you follow my advice to use a table less model with schema you will also have more power over input creation and validation.